# Is there a way to determine what is powering the content behind a URL?

Tags: 7, search, uri

I have a relative URL in a large site that I inherited: `/my-url`.

For the life of me I can't find the View, Module, or other content that shows how to edit this URL. I've grepped the code base, and searched the database, but can't find it.

How can I tell how this URL gets edited? Is there some kind of search modules/views/blocks by URL?

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking in the `menu_router` table, where the `path` column contains values like `node/%/revisions/view`. Also, the `url_alias` table has a `source` column (to check against the `menu_router` table) and the alias defining a path like `/my-url`.

I also use TextWrangler and PHPStorm to inspect my code. You could try to search.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and the [Devel Themer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) module to check template file possibilities.

Check your themes /templates folder and template.php for modifications.

A lot of themes apply the nid or tid as a css class to the body or elsewhere in the form of `node-123` or `taxonomy-term-123` etc.  You can check for this and try visiting `/node/123/edit` for example.

Another possibility is that it is coming from a custom module, so check the module list for any module that could be custom.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your aliases. To do this, go to yoursite/admin/config/search/path/list, where you can filter for a url (like my-url). If it comes up, it will tell you content item it is aliasing, and you can edit it from there.

If your using [ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools), you might also want to check to see if it's being controlled by the page manager. If page manager is enabled, then you can look at admin/structure/pages to see if any of those match the offending url. I suspect this is the most likely culprit, as it wouldn't show up in the url_alias table of the db, as those paths are stored in page_manager_paths.

Answer (score 0):

Last and least an easy and crude method. Just dump your database using mysqldump into a file and grep this URL. Locate the table then locate the module.

Comment: I want to believe that would work, but what if that url was being created via a URL pattern that included, say, a taxonomy term? If the URL in question was `term1/node1` (conforming to the pattern [taxonomy_term]/[node_title]), then you'd have to search for each part of the URL separately, wouldn't you?